# TestRestTemplate is returning 415 Unsupported Media Type for POST call on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am writing functional tests for my *Spring Boot 2* application.

I used `TestRestTemplate` for functional testing. It was working fine for GET APIs. But now for testing POST API, it is returning **415 Unsupported Media Type**. I am passing Content-Type and Accept header with value `application/json`.

This is happening only when running the test on *IntelliJ 19*. It is running fine on commandline. I am using *Gradle* build tool.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("Path/rest")    
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping(value = "/api", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> getResponse(
    @RequestBody Request request,
    @RequestHeader(name = "Transaction-GUID", required = false) String transactionGUIDheader, HttpServletRequest request)
    throws InvalidInputException, ExternalServiceGenericException {

    Response response = service.getResponse(request, transactionGUID);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Functional Test:

```
@ActiveProfiles(FUNCTIONAL_TEST)
@SpringBootTest (webEnvironmentSpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 9000)
public class ControllerFunctionalTest {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        WireMock.reset();
    }

    @Test
public void testControllerPost(){

   HttpEntity<Reqeust>  request = createRq(String str1, String str2);
   callWiremock();
   String url = "http://localhost:8080/Path/rest/api";
   ResponseEntity<Response> response =
        testRestTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Response.class);

    assertNotNull(response);
}
```

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Usually, the HTTP 415 is returned when you send `Content-Type` header which doesn't match the actual body of the request. For example, sending `Content-Type` with HTTP GET method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just put content type in header (in http Entity).

```
  MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
  headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
```